# Chrome Devtools: Save specific requests in Network Tab

Tags: http, web-crawler, google-chrome-devtools

Can I save just specific requests in the Chrome Devtools Network tab?

It would be very useful to me since our company uses web crawling to fetch info from extranets, and the most I can do is to record (with the rec button) all the requests made to reach for a specific info, and if I want to save the desired requests/responses in a file to analyze them later, all I can do is to save it all as a .har file, which saves EVERYTHING, including every resource (images, css, js, etc), filling the file with lots of useless info for my purpose.

Another way would be to copy and paste just the requests filtered with Documents + XHR + Other, which I don't like either because it's not structured in a JSON format like the HAR file does.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44887215/632951

Comment: This is the way I have done it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58325758/create-a-har-file-with-xhr-request-only-in-chrome-dev-tools

Answer (score 2):

There is a chrome extension named Network.Recorder which retains Network Requests when ext icon is clicked on, and when clicked off, prompts you to save content to a local file. This might help.

Comment: I can't find it with that name. Is it still available?

Comment: sorry I had the incorrect name. here is the link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/network-record/ihbkogfblhfbnompooimhejpkidoipcl?hl=en

Comment: I see that this is still available, though it appears it does the same thing, and records everything, not a single request.