# Copy multiple network responses in chrome devtools network console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to copy all network responses from the filtered list of requests from the network tab under Chrome's devtools.

I read about the solution of copy all requests' URLs at [Multiple URLs copy in Sources/Network tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200450/multiple-urls-copy-in-sources-network-tab?newreg=7d6ffd5426924800842f5b4594d3cdc0)
But I can't figure out how to access the decoded response body from requests.

The solution at [Chrome Devtools: Save specific requests in Network Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955932/chrome-devtools-save-specific-requests-in-network-tab) works, but I want a solution that only extracts responses from the filtered request list under the network tab.

Comment: I found out about "static async _copyResponse(request)" function from https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/master/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/network/NetworkLogView.js?autodive=0%2F

I can get a network request from devtools for devtools(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200450/multiple-urls-copy-in-sources-network-tab?newreg=7d6ffd5426924800842f5b4594d3cdc0):
request = UI.panels.network._networkLogView._dataGrid._rootNode._flatNodes[0]._request

But "UI.panels.network._networkLogView" has no function of _copyResponse.

Comment: I haven't found an answer yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple URLs copy in Sources/Network tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200450/multiple-urls-copy-in-sources-network-tab)

Answer (score 8):

Inspecting the source code of devtools reveals we need [contentData() method](https://crsrc.org/third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/core/sdk/NetworkRequest.ts;l=1216;drc=251d77980742d232fcbb0e0e492d9cec4155f299).

The how-to-use instructions are the same as in [Multiple URLs copy in Sources/Network tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41202159).

```js
await (async () => {
  const getContent = r => r.url() && !r.url().startsWith('data:') && r.contentData();
  const nodes = UI.panels.network.networkLogView.dataGrid.rootNode().flatChildren();
  const requests = nodes.map(n => n.request());
  const contents = await Promise.all(requests.map(getContent));
  return contents.map((data, i) => {
    const r = requests[i];
    const url = r.url();
    const body = data?.content;
    const content = !data ? url :
      r.contentType().isTextType() ? data :
        typeof body !== 'string' ? body :
          `data:${r.mimeType}${data.encoded ? ';base64' : ''},${body}`;
    return {url, content};
  });
})();
```

Tested in Chrome 111. For older versions of Chrome see the revisions of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Update of @wOxxOm's excellent answer but for 2023:

```js
(async () => {
  const getContent = r => r.url() && !r.url().startsWith('data:') && r.contentData();
  const nodes = UI.panels.network.networkLogView.dataGrid.rootNode().flatChildren();
  const requests = nodes.map(n => n.request());
  const contents = await Promise.all(requests.map(getContent));
  const looks = contents.map((data, i) => {
    const r = requests[i];
    const url = r.url();
    const content = !data ? 'data is encoded inside the data url already, duh' :
      r.contentType().isTextType() ? data :
        Common.ContentProvider.contentAsDataURL(data, r.mimeType, r.contentEncoded());
    return {url, content};
  });
  console.log(looks);
})();
```

Ran via the console when you're inspecting (CTRL+SHIFT+I) a popped out inspector window on the network tab. That's right, meta-inspection!
CTRL+SHIFT+I