# Create PDF file from application/pdf server response in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: pdf, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to convert the below response which I got from the Chrome Dev Tools to a PDF file?

```
%PDF-1.5
%âãÏÓ
38 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 189
/Height 100
/ColorSpace /DeviceGray
/Matte [0 0 0]
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Interpolate false
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 3345
>>
.....
```

I know this is the RAW PDF data so I tried to create a pdf file out of this in Node.js but the output was a blank PDF file.

There's some conversion missing which I am not able to figure out. Any sort of help is deeply appreciated

Comment: Could be a codepage problem e.g. maybe you're reading the response as text, instead of binary data (ArrayBuffer or Blob).

Comment: @wOxxOm I got the above data from inspecting in the Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools. Was thinking if I can take that response and write in binary to a pdf file. Am I making sense?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "take". You can't do it by copypasting certainly.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes most certainly. There is a response tab when you click on a network request, and you can see what the request returned (in raw form). Was thinking is there a way I can take whatever is returned and create a PDF file out of it

Comment: You can do it in devtools-on-devtools, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57782978) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server).